# Making All App Vibrations Stop Setting

Tags: ios, swift, vibration

I am trying to create a button within my app that turns of the vibrations that occur when some buttons are pressed within the app.

I have used the:

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))

code to enable the vibrate on certain button presses - but I want the user to be able to turn off the vibration, if they so wanted.

Is there a way to disable all vibrations from a single .disable or .invalidate type of way (those examples are the only code cancelling things I could think of)

Answer (score 0):

You can create one bool and store it's state to `NSUserDefaults` then add a `if` condition for vibration like this:

```
if allowVibration {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
}
```

And it will not enter into this if condition if `allowVibration` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store a `bool` that keeps track of whether or not to play the vibration. If you don't want to keep track of this between application sessions just use a `bool`.

```
// Get NSUserDefaults
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

// Some button that would turn off vibration
@IBAction func turnVibrateOff(sender: AnyObject) {
    defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "vibrate")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

// Some button that would turn on vibration
@IBAction func turnVibrateOn(sender: AnyObject) {
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "vibrate")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}

// Then just check against the key we've created
func shouldWeVibrate() {
    if defaults.boolForKey("vibrate") {
        // Vibrate
    }
}
```